# PHP: Is it possible to run multiple background process in parallel on Windows Server?

Tags: php, windows, background-process

I'm working on a project using codeigniter 3 on windows server. It processes some data in a background process after user uploads and saves it into DB. It is totally fine. Here's the code

```
    private function _run_in_background()
    {
        $ip = $this->helper->get_ip_address();
        $command = "php -f ".FCPATH."index.php auth run_in_background 0 $ip";
        
        $this->_command($command);
    }

    private function _command($command)
    {
        if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows")
        {
            pclose(popen("start \"run_in_background\" $command", "r"));
        }
    }
```

The issue comes after the user tries to upload data from another pc. Because the trigger for running the background process is if user successfully saves the data into DB, then the background process runs.

The question is, it possible to runs multiple background processes at the same time?

When the current user is running a background process, the others don't need to wait?

Comment: there should be no problem for multiple php processes running in the background. (just like it is not necessary to wait for one user to complete doing a file upload operation before another one user uploads)

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I got an issue when user A uploads the data and triggered the background process, it's means the background process is running. when it's running, user B uploads the data from another PC and triggered this background process one more times, and the background process that triggered by user B won't runs parallel, but waits the first one done. that's the issue. any ideas?

Comment: From your scripts, you are trying to do `php -f ".FCPATH."index.php auth run_in_background 0 $ip`. (executing a index.php with parameters $ip on the background). What actually does this background command do ?

Comment: the background process does some requests to the API from the data taken from DB. let's say the data is 500 rows, loop through the data, make an API requests, and update the data from API responses

Answer (score 1):

with `popen()` it is possible, but you won't have much control over the process:

```php
$command = 'START "" /B '.$command.' 2>&1';
if (!($a = popen($command, 'r')) ||
    fread($a, 1000) !== 'TASK STARTED')
{
  # handle error
}
pclose($a);
```

doing both `pclose(popen(..))` doesn't leave an open pipe for `start` to start the script (it terminates right away), so, the reading of STDOUT (blocking, the script must output something) and closing the pipe afterwards - does the trick (for me, win2008r2). though, avoid more output from the script.